# perl script to merge multiple xml files in one file

Tags: perl

I have thousands of XML files which I want to merge into one single XML file. In java I can do it in seconds but very new in perl script. Can anybody please suggest How can we do this using **perl script**? Every suggestion is appreciated. All the XML files have same structure, same encoding. The only thing different is the data b/w the tags.

Comment: As it stands, this question is likely to be closed for lack of detail - what is the structure of these XML files, and how will that structure be merged? Moreover, what have you tried? I'm sure there are plenty of XML libraries for Perl; have you looked at any? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: The most important aspect of any Stack Overflow question is including what you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks for replying IMSoP and Christopher. I am very new to the perl script therefore not familiar so much from from the perls and its libraries. For the additional info I would like to include that All the XML files have same structure, same encoding. The only thing different is the data b/w the tags. In java I can do it in few seconds but no idea of perl script.

Answer (score 4):

Parse both docs. I'd use XML::LibXML. Find the node that is to be the parent of the nodes you want to merge in. For each node you want to merge in, insert that node as a child of the previously found parent.